# Dedupe a collection variable in salesforce flow

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, collection, variable

I have a flow that ultimately stores a collection variable I am calling var_Opportunities. Due to the nature of how I am getting records, there are sometimes duplicate opportunity IDs in this collection variable. So when I use it as an assignment to update a record (as a count), it can double count certain things.

I need to figure out a way to either update this collection variable or create a new collection variable that has a list of de-duped Opportunity Ids. I know there is an "Unofficial SF" collection deduper, but it involves Apex, and this needs to be a before-save flow. I found a few articles online on workarounds, but they involve taking two collection variables and merging the duplicates into one. I have one collection variable, and ultimately need to arrive at a deduped list of Opportunity IDs.
Due to the nature of the request, my "Get records" element needs to be an "or" statement, which is why duplicate opportunityIDs appear on the collection variable. I've hit a wall so any help would be appreciated.

TL;DR: I have a collection variable in a flow called var_Opportunities.  Due to how the get records element works for this use case, it sometimes has duplicate OpportunityIDs in the collection variable. Need to de-dupe.

Thanks in advance. [image]